# Sonarqube is giving HashMap initalization code compliant issue

Tags: java, hashmap, sonarqube, initialization, java-stream

I have this code where I am initializing this `HashMap` like:

```
final HashMap<String, String> propertiesValueMap = new HashMap<String, String>(){{
            put(SOME_STRING, SOME_STRING);
            put(SOME_STRING, SOME_STRING);
            put(SOME_STRING, SOME_STRING);
         }};
```

The above code is giving non complaint code issue in SonarQube.
is there any other way by which i can initialize?

I know one way like

```
Stream.of(new String[][]{
            { SOME_STRING, SOME_STRING},{SOME_STRING, SOME_STRING}
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(data->data[0],data->data[1]
    ));
```

But this will return me `Map<String,String>` and I want `HashMap<String,String>`.

Answer (score 2):

As Sonarsource saying:

> Double Brace Initialization (DBI) is so obscure...

[Double Brace Initialization should not be used](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-3599)

You could do something like

```
Map<String, String> propertiesValueMap = createMap();
 
private static Map<String, String> createMap() {
    Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    myMap.put(SOME_STRING, SOME_STRING)
    return myMap;
}
```

Or, if you are creating an immutable Map and using Java 9 :

```java
import static java.util.Map.entry;    

Map<String, String> propertiesValueMap = Map.ofEntries(
    entry("SOME_STRING", "SOME_STRING"),
    entry("SOME_STRING2", "SOME_STRING2")
);
```

Comment: okay thank you, i found one more way like new HashMap(Stream.of(new String[][]{
            { SOME_STRING, SOME_STRING},{SOME_STRING, SOME_STRING}
    }).collect(Collectors.toMap(data->data[0],data->data[1]
    )));

Answer (score 1):

This issue arose because you are writing your code against concrete implementations. Which doesn't bays you anything. It only makes your code inflexible, more difficult to maintain, more verbose and less expressive. Consider reading this question [What does it mean to "program to an interface"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383947/what-does-it-mean-to-program-to-an-interface).

In regard to `Collectors.toMap()` (*which expects only two arguments*) currently, it does return you a `HashMap`. And it is not specified, because sometime in the future it could be replaced with an enhanced *general purpose implementation* that will better in some cases than `HashMap`. If you would write your code against `Map` interface instead of requesting a particular implementation, you would get an implementation for free without changing the code.

As I've mentioned, you can ***request a particular implementation*** of the `Map` interface by using a flavor of [`toMap()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap(java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.Function,java.util.function.BinaryOperator,java.util.function.Supplier)) that expects a supplier `mapFactory`.

```
Collector<T,?,M> toMap(Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
                       Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,
                       BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction,
                       Supplier<M> mapFactory)
```

But my suggestion is to use it when need a *special purpose implementation* like `LinkedHashMap`, `TreeMap`, `WeakedHashMap`, etc. The best current *general purpose implementation* (which currently a `HashMap`) will be provided to you by default, just write your code against interfaces, and you'll be fine.

An example of usage of this flavor of `toMap`:

```
Map<String, String> result =
    list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.toMap(
              data->data[0],
              data->data[1],
              (left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError(); }, // this argument is meant to resolve duplicates and because all keys are expected to be unique it'll trows an error if duplicate will occure
              LinkedHashMap::new));
```

In regard to `new HashMap<String, String>(){{ someCode }};`, I suggest you to utilize Java 9 static methods of the `Map` interface [`Map.of()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V,K,V,K,V)) or [`Map.ofEntries()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)) instead. It makes your code leaner and saves from disadvantages that double brace initialization can bring, like possibility of **memory leaks**, which might emerge because the anonymous inner class that it creates under the hood would hold reference to the instance of the enclosing class. That's why this practice is considered to be an *antipattern*.

Comment: If you expect no duplicate keys, you can use `(left, right) -> { throw new AssertionError(); }` to emphasize this assumption and be sure not to continue with corrupted data if this fundamental assumption turns out to be wrong.

Comment: @Holger Thanks, you are right, it will be not clear for the reader of the code that here `mergeFunction` isn't expected to be used, and it's better to emphasize that by throwing an error. Amended.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Java 9, the easiest way to define a fixed `Map<K,V>` is to just use one of [the `Map.of(...)` variants](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#of(K,V)) (or [`ofEntries`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#ofEntries(java.util.Map.Entry...)) if you need more than 10 entries).

```
Map<String, String> myMap = Map.of(
    KEY1, VALUE1,
    KEY2, VALUE2);
```

That one returns a non-specific `Map<K,V>` though (i.e. the exact type is not guaranteed, but [some properties](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#unmodifiable) of the result are), so if you *need* a `HashMap` then the easiest way is to just pass the result of the above to `new HashMap<>()`:

```
HashMap<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>(Map.of(
    KEY1, VALUE1,
    KEY2, VALUE2));
```

While this *does* create two maps (one of which will quickly be garbage-collected), I consider this an acceptable drawback, given that you avoid creating a whole new class just for initializing some values.